# Getting MySQL records where field is empty

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to get all rows where `MyField` is either empty or may contain whitespace.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `MyField` = ""
```

This works fine in phpMyAdmin but not in PHP for some reason..

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `MyField` <> ""
```

I'm not sure how this works but it returns rows where `MyField` is not empty

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(`MyField`)) = ""
```

Empty result set

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure they are not NULL values? If so, use `WHERE myField IS NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TRIM function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) does the job:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 |      |
|  2 |      |
|  3 | test |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM users WHERE TRIM(name)='';
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 |      |
|  2 |      |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eb68/1)

Comment: You can also use the `WHERE name = ' '` condition

Comment: @ypercube Yes, as the PO said, there may be only 1 space, it's probably faster to use `name='' OR name=' '`, like you said. But TRIM is better, as it covers arbitrary number of spaces (just in case).

Comment: @user4035 Have you tried `WHERE name = ' '` when there are more than one spaces in the column?

Comment: @ypercube looking. Yes, seems to be working, trying to break :P

Comment: @ypercube SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=''; also gave me both records

Comment: @ypercube Yes, trailing spaces are insignificant for char, varchar and text. While for binary strings they are significant: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html

Comment: Yes, it's also one of those things that depend on the DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, SQL-Server, Oracle, all have slight differences on how they have implemented string equivalence checks.)

Comment: @ypercube Interesting, why did the PO claim, that `WHERE name=''` didn't work for him in php and worked in phpMyAdmin? It should work in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

does the field default to NULL?

If so did you try:

```
WHERE myfield IS NULL OR myfield = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `MyField`  != "";
```

Comment: Is `!=` a mysql operator?

Comment: `!=` is (in MySQL) same as the (standard) `<>`